# Where can I get the sheet music for the song Crescent Moon Dance?

Tags: music, hibike-euphonium

I hope this is not too off-topic, but I recently watched *Hibike! Euphonium* (*Sound! Euphonium*), and I was wondering if anybody knows where I can find sheet music for the piece that they play in the competition. Specifically, I'm looking for *Crescent Moon Dance* by *Namie Horikawa* (I don't know if this is an alias or not). I play the trumpet, and I really wanted to try out Kousaka's solo. If anybody could help me out, that would be appreciated!

Comment: When I was in Japan I saw them on a cover of a japanese brass magazine called Brass. There's a possibility it could be in that issue

Comment: Included with the BD/DVD release? https://twitter.com/VandaHirosaki/status/599149966670438401/photo/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official website](http://anime-eupho.com/product/bddvd/oritoku/), the official sheet music for Crescent Moon Dance 「三日月の舞」 was given as extra on purchase of the Volume 1 of BD/DVD at certain stores in Japan<sup>1</sup>. Unfortunately, Volume 1 already went on sale on Jun 17, 2015.

Likewise, the sheet music for the opening 「DREAM SOLISTER」 and the ending 「Tutti」 will be given as extra on purchase of BD/DVD Volume 2 and 3 respectively.

<sup><sup>1</sup> The stores as listed on official website: 玉光堂、バンダレコード・ライオン堂、ＪＥＵＧＩＡ、十字屋CROSS、新星堂、山野楽器、ヤマハミュージックリテイリング</sup>

The advertisement, as [posted by one of the stores on Twitter](https://twitter.com/VandaHirosaki/status/599149966670438401/photo/1), inviting people to reserve a copy of the BD/DVD for the sheet music:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's too bad they only released it with the DVD, but hopefully I can find a copy.

Comment: @user2950265: It's not really included with the BD/DVD - like how limited version is more expensive and comes with more stuffs. It's a first come first serve, store-specific extra. Some stores I listed above also give out the music sheet if you buy the BD/DVD from their online shop (though I don't know if any is still available).

Answer (score 4):

There are [multiple](https://musescore.com/sheetmusic?text=crescent+moon+dance) fan transcriptions/arrangements of the piece available on MuseScore:

---

- <s>[Crescent Moon Dance from Hibike! Euphonium v1.1 | Last updated 03/07/2016](https://musescore.com/user/75149/scores/1043236),  Maelic</s>

  - [Crescent Moon Dance](https://musescore.com/matthewlefebvre/scores/1982536), Matthew LeFebvre (**Updated version** of the above)

    - [Crescent Moon Dance [Simple band]](https://musescore.com/user/3453076/scores/2732726), Leonardo Pereira (edited version of above)
    - [Crescent Moon Dance](https://musescore.com/user/17053691/scores/4143786), Musicmaker3000 (edited version of above)
- [Crescent Moon Dance (with extended oboe solo!)](https://musescore.com/wjswlghks/crescent-moon-dance-with-extended-oboe-solo), French Horn Nerd
- [crescent moon dance](https://musescore.com/user/3438701/scores/2766636), fullgames
- [Crescent Moon Dance](https://musescore.com/devils-calculator/scores/3401111), Tenors3
- [Crescent Moon Dance](https://musescore.com/gaussfrigate/scores/3709781), GaussFrigate (Digitization/transcription of **original score**)
- [Crescent Moon Dance](https://musescore.com/user/2996206/scores/4146721), Little Mozart

---

- [Crescent Moon Dance](https://musescore.com/user/5488551/scores/4716476), Aidan Chang (arranged for brass band)
- [Crescent Moon Dance - Tuba Euphonium Quartet](https://musescore.com/user/1009596/scores/5015204), MeTheDwarfpro

---

- [Crescent Moon Dance Trumpet Solo](https://musescore.com/user/1313741/scores/2963431), chuazd

---

According to the [Hibike Euphonium wiki](http://hibike-euphonium.wikia.com/wiki/Crescent_Moon_Dance):

> As of 2016, the sheet music has been released for purchase by Japanese wind ensembles, and is gaining recognition as a legitimate piece of wind repertoire in the country.

So, if you have contacts in the Japanese orchestral/wind band scores world, you should be able to purchase a copy.

Answer (score 3):

Crescent Moon Dance 「三日月の舞」 trumpet solo, as transcribed by [Skye van Duuren](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLmYuODzssAtpIiJAyYPPcA) on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/VU27_28hoKs):

[image]

Comment: The same answer has already been posted...

Comment: @Alagaros: No, my answer doesn't cover fan transcription.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm super duper late to this thread and you probably have found this info already, but since this thread is one of the top google results for "crescent moon dance" I thought I would reply here.

The sheet music is available for purchase at [Print Gakufu](https://www.print-gakufu.com/score/detail/136344/). Use Chrome to translate the page (it is all in Japanese). They block any non-Japanese credit cards through their integrated credit card payment service, however the payment service Rakuten is accepted. Rakuten will allow you to use any credit card to make the payment.

IF YOU ARE OUTSIDE OF JAPAN YOU MUST USE RAKUTEN TO PAY FOR SHEET MUSIC FROM PRINT GAKUFU!!!